# activity_main.xml não mostra layout, mostra apenas um ícone de uma pequena chave Inglesa e a mensagem: "Toogle tools visibility and position"

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, layout

Esse é um programa que fiz ha algum tempo atrás. Uma calculadora simples.
Procurei por opções de visualização do Android Studio, mas parece coisa de programa.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    tools:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum0"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num0"
        android:text="@string/btn0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumMenos"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numMenos"
        android:text="@string/btnMenos"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumMais" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum1"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num1"
        android:text="@string/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum3"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num3"
        android:text="@string/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumDivide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumIgual"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numIgual"
        android:text="@string/btnIgual"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumDivide" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumBk"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numBack"
        android:text="@string/btnBack"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumIgual"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumPorcento"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numPorcento"
        android:text="@string/btnPorcento"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumVezes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Caixa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumClr"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="onLimpa"
        android:text="@string/btnLimpa"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnLiga"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Caixa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum7"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num7"
        android:text="@string/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLiga" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLiga"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:onClick="CalcLigar"
        android:text="@string/btnOn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Caixa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num4"
        android:text="@string/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum5"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num5"
        android:text="@string/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNum4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum8"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num8"
        android:text="@string/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNum7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumClr" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum2"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num2"
        android:text="@string/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNum1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumVezes"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numVezes"
        android:text="@string/btnVezes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Caixa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumMais"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numMais"
        android:text="@string/btnMais"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumVezes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumDivide"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="numDivide"
        android:text="@string/btnDivide"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumMenos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum6"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num6"
        android:text="@string/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumMenos"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNum9"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="num9"
        android:text="@string/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumMais"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumPorcento" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumPonto"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:onClick="numPonto"
        android:text="@string/btnPonto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNum0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNum2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Caixa"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/StrDica"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/Caixa"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução:

Utilizei o EditText  porém, não sei ainda porque, ele não funcionou na nova versão do Android Studio. Alterei o EditText para:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Caixa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/StrDica"
    android:text="@string/Caixa"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Após essa Edição, meu Layout voltou a aparecer.
Na verdade eu criei um novo layout, copiei e colei o XML e percebi que tinha o mesmo resultado. Comecei a copiar item a item, até encontrar qual deles estavam bugando meu layout.

Obrigado.
Ricardo